# How to make a bar plot in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to build graphs in Python, using this dataset:

```
    df  = pd.read_csv("Sales.csv")
    df
```

[image: sales df in Python]
Then I try to build a bar chart using this code:

```
df_product_group = df.groupby('Product').sum()
product_group = df_product_group.groupby(['Total Amount'])
product_group.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=[16,6], colormap='winter')
```

It produces a lot of error codes, including this at the end of the line:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate)
   3289                 in_axis, name, level, gpr = False, None, gpr, None
   3290             else:
-> 3291                 raise KeyError(gpr)
   3292         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
   3293             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: 'Total Amount'
```

What did I do wrong here? And how do I make a bar plot the right way here?
Thank you beforehand.

Comment: It's clear in your dataframe `df_product_group`, there is no column named `Total Amount`

Comment: what you want ? it is unclear

Comment: @WeNYoBen I want to make a bar plot using the data.

Comment: First, see the output of your code `df_product_group = df.groupby('Product').sum()` by printing the result: `print(df_product_group)` to check whether `Total Amount` is in your dataframe before you group them.

Comment: @YusufUMS, eh, you're right. How come it's not there?

Comment: Change your code to `df_product_group = df.groupby('Product').agg({'Total Amount':'sum'}).reset_index()`